# The type or namespace name 'Game1' could not be found

Tags: c#, xna

I created a new xna 3.1 project, and copied some source code from a document to the new project and was presented with that error. I have read that it is to do with namespaces, however the namespace is unchanged, and i honestly do not know what else to do. Help would be great.

The error is being underlined in the program.cs file:

```
using System;

namespace MyFirstWindowsGame
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (Game1 game = new Game1())
            {
                game.Run();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the above source code, game1 is being underlined.

Comment: Well, do you have a `Game1` class and are you importing it with `using`?

Comment: Is that your entire program?   I don't see anywhere that you've actually defined a type called Game1

Comment: I suspect you need to include the `Game` library, both as a reference in your project, and with `using` in your source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that the compiler can't find the type `Game1`. Depending on what exactly did you copy and how, you might need to copy the file containing the `Game1` class too or it's possible the type is in another namespace.

Comment: Oh yes! it was not being used in the game1.cs file. It's Now fixed, thank you!.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new game project a class is auto-generated, with the default name of Game1. When you copied code you probably replaced the default Game descendent with something else. Look in your code for a class that descends from Game. Replace Game1 with that class name in the sample code you posted.

For example, if your game class is called MyWindowsGame, the Program class would look like this:

```
namespace MyFirstWindowsGame 
{ 
    static class Program 
    { 
        /// <summary> 
        /// The main entry point for the application. 
        /// </summary> 
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        { 
            using (MyWindowsGame game = new MyWindowsGame()) 
            { 
                game.Run(); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Also, the namespace you're using is `MyFirstWindowsGame'. If you copied code from somewhere, make sure the namespace is the same in that code file.